# Google App Engine Datastore Entity properties with different types

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How do I create a property that can accept both a `ArrayList<Integer>` and `ArrayList<String>`?

I tried setting it as `ArrayList<Object>` but it doesn't accept either parameters.

Comment: You can do it using the native Datastore API (instead of using JDO/JPA/Objectify).

Comment: I would test how this will behave - specifically how it will affect the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Low-level Datastore API to set the same property to either `ArrayList<Integer>` (which will be stored and retrieved as `ArrayList<Long>`, by the way) or `ArrayList<String>`. You should remember, however, to type-check when you retrieve the value of this property (casting from `ArrayList<Long>` to `ArrayList<String>` or vice versa is not possible), and you will have to write this code yourself.

In general, this is not a good practice. Strong typing is an advantage of Java. Use it.